# Trying to make control-f search exactly like control-s does!

Tags: key-bindings, search

I am trying to configure Emacs to not only use CUA, but also for `control-f` to search exactly like `control-s` does in the standard configuration.

What I have achieved is that I can key in `control-f` and search for something and find it. However, when I press `control-f` twice, I do not find the next occurrence of the search string. (Like what happens when I in the original configuration press `control-s` twice.

Also, with `control-s control-w` I could mark a word and then search for it. This does not work either with `control-f`.

My configuration:

```
(global-set-key [(control f)] 'isearch-forward)
```

I am on Windows, if that matters. But ideally I would like to apply this to Mac and Linux too so I get the same keybindings on all my computers.

Comment: What `C-s` does in the standard configuration is not `search-forward` but `isearch-forward`.

Comment: @Omar, thanks - I accidentally wrote `search-forward here`, I meant `isearch-forward`. I manually typed the question instead of copying verbatim from the config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, we need not only `(global-set-key [(control f)] 'isearch-forward)` but also:

```
; isearch requires some customization to work with none default keys,
; since it uses its own keymap during a search.  These changes are *always*
; active, and not toggled with touchstream mode!  Luckly for us, the keys are
; we need are not used by isearch so there are no conflicts.
(define-key isearch-mode-map [(control f)] 'isearch-repeat-forward)
```

Source: http://fingerfans.dreamhosters.com/archive/attachments/5023_cnewcombe_emacs_like_windows.txt

Comment: I presume the two `[(control f)]` bindings are the only ones you *need* for your question as stated?

Comment: @phils, yes. I removed the others from my block quote.